# Necessity of surjectivity in :$\phi:G \rightarrow G' $ is a surjective homorphism, then G' is abelian if G is.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\phi:G \rightarrow G' $ is a surjective homorphism, then it's easy to prove that if $G$ is abelian then so is $G'$.

It is quite easy to prove this relation, but I don't understand the need for the surjective homorphism. If we remove the condition of surjective homorphism, even then $G'$ can be abelian ( I do realise that under such condition $G'$ will be abelian in itself and we won't be needing homorphism at all.)

Comment: Often $G'$ denotes the "derived subgroup", i.e., the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$, so $\phi\colon G\rightarrow H$ is perhaps  a better notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we remove the requirement of a surjective homomorphism, them $G'$ *might* be abelian, but it doesn't *have* to be. If we require $\phi$ to be surjective, and $G$ abelian, then $G'$ *must* be abelian.

For instance, let $f:C_3 \to S_3$ be the inclusion of the rotations of a triangle to the full symmetry group of a triangle. $S_3$ is clearly not abelian (being well-known as the smallest non-abelian group), but $C_3$ *is* abelian.

The reason we need surjectivity is that given $a', b' \in G'$ we want to compare $a'b'$ with $b'a'$. The only help we have is that $G$ is abelian, so we find $a, b$ such that $\phi(a) = a'$ and $\phi(b) = b'$. We know that $ab = ba$, which by the defining properties of homomorphisms give $a'b' = b'a'$.

Finding such $a, b$ *requires* that we know $\phi$ to be surjective. For instance, in the counterexample above, $(12)$ and $(123)$ in $S_3$ do not commute, but there is no $\sigma \in C_3$ such that $f(\sigma) = (12)$, which is why the above argument fails to prove $S_3$ as abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Since the zero group is abelian we have $0\to G'$ for any group $G'$. But if you want some nontrivial example, there are plenty.

For example, let $G$ be abelian and $G'=G\times H$ where $H$ is not abelian. Then $G'$ is not abelian also since for noncommutative elements $h,h'\in H$ we have $$(0,h)+(0,h')=(0,h+h')\neq (0,h'+h)=(0,h')+(0,h).$$ Then let $\phi\colon G\to G'$, $g\mapsto (g,0)$. This is a nonsurjective homomorphism from an abelian group $G$ to $G'$.

Another way to see this is by using the isomorphism theorem for surjective group morphisms which states that if we have a surjective group morphism $\phi\colon G\to G'$, then $G'\cong G/ker(\phi)$. Then since quotient groups of an abelian group are always abelian, namely $G/ker(\phi)$ is abelian then $G'$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $ab = ba $ then $$\phi(a)\phi(b) = \phi (ab) = \phi (ba) = \phi(b)\phi(a).$$

Comment: I know this one but I want to know the need for surjective mapping. Why homomorphism should be surjective?

Comment: @user3135030, you need that every element of $G'$ be image of an element of $G$.